# The use of subindices with greek letters

Tags: subscripts, greek

I need to use subindices with greek letters. But I find that the result is sometimes decipherable.

Examples:

```
$\alpha_{H}$, $\gamma_{H}$
```

Do you have any suggestion in that regard? Of course, I do not want to use another subindex than "H".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try it this way:

```
\def\H{\rule{0pt}{1.5ex}H}

$\alpha_H \gamma_H $ $\alpha_{\H} \gamma_{\H} $
```

Comment: Or just an empty supercript `$\alpha^{}_{H}$` often helps

Comment: @Herbert Could you please explain why that works? Thanks!

Comment: @CravingSpirit: It insert an invisible vertical rule before H which is always of the same height.

Comment: @Herbert Oh, I see. It also has something to do with the length of the rule, the longer it is, the lower the "H" will sink. Thanks!